# Replace comma with semi-colon in only 3 columns with VBA within .csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, replace, find

Let me see if I can try this again. I have a CSV file. It stands for comma separated value, which is a file format. In this file, there are several columns of varied data in each cell below. If I open the CSV file in Notepad, each "cell" is separated by a comma, hence the file format name. In Excel, there are no commas. The cells are obviously separated by table border lines. What I'm trying to do is replace the commas in columns F through H, rows 2 and below (that also have data) with a semi-colon. The rest of the commas in the file stay as is.

Comment: Record a vba macro, replace comma with ; and look a t the code

Comment: I have the semi-colons figured out. Now, I am trying to figure out how to remove the commas in the vColumns array (cols F through H). This is a csv file. The comma is considered the list separator.

Comment: @dacrovinunghi - I did that already, and I realized that the data inside the cells vary. So, looking at such code is useless. I'm looking to replace the default list separator ( , - comma) with a ; (semi-colon) for 3 columns.

Comment: we need a sample, it 's strange

Comment: @dacrovinunghi - please see my update. Thanks.

Comment: @dacrovinunghi - The top is originally how the file comes. The bottom is how I'm trying to make it. Obviously, the value in the cells have been changed, per confidentiality.

Comment: first replace ,, with , then use your macro

Comment: @dacrovinunghi - And yes, I only need it for rows 2 and below. The first row shouldn't have this replacement. That's why you see the 2 there (in the code, I mean).

Comment: @dacrovinunghi - No, I can't replace those two ,, - that's the way it's supposed to be. It's only for columns F through H, not columns A or B.

Comment: I dont understand; is the data are in csv file or already imported in excel columns ? if in excel colum just make a column with A1 & ",," & B1 & "," so on. then write this comumn to csv file (neware of colum length )

Comment: @dacrovinunghi - It is a csv file that eventually gets imported into Excel columns.

Comment: so no comma remaining in columns ?

Comment: Not exactly. There still needs to be commas. Just not in the columns I listed. Only semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddSemicolonsINSTALLMENT()
    Dim vColumns As Variant, vColumn As Variant
    Dim rCol As Range, rCell As Range

    vColumns = Array("F", "G", "H")

    For Each vColumn In vColumns
        Set rCol = Range(Range(vColumn & "2"), Cells(Rows.Count, vColumn).End(xlUp)) '<<EDIT
        For Each rCell In rCol.Cells
            rCell.Value = ";" & Replace(rCell.Value, ",", ";") & ";"
        Next rCell
    Next vColumn

End Sub
```

Comment: It's still not removing the commas in the selected columns.

Comment: This is a CSV file you've opened in Excel, correct?  I feel there's something significant missing from your question about exactly what you're wanting to do...  It looks like you want to replace the separator comma with a semicolon, but it's unclear how that will work once the CSV is open in excel (since at that point the separator commas will not be there)

Comment: Yes, it's a CSV file I opened in Excel. Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I've been trying to figure out how to do that without manually having to go to every cell and replace it.

Comment: See my edit above: tested and works for me (at least, it does what your posted code seems to be intended to do)

Comment: I'm sorry. But it seems like I'm not explaining it quite as well as I thought. I understand in Excel there are no commas visible in any of the cells in the CSV file. However, when I open the CSV file in Notepad, they are there. The commas in the specific columns are the ones I'm trying to replace. Are there any books you could recommend in this area of specialty?

Comment: OK I think it's a little clearer now - you want to replace the commas *between* ColF and ColG, and *between* ColG and ColH ?  When you talk about commas "in columns" then it's a little confusing.  What you'll need to do is open the file as text, using VBA's built-in file capabilities, or something like the FileSystemObject, and do some manipulation on the content of each line.  If you can post a sample of the type of file you're working with (a few lines would be fine) then someone might help.

Comment: Yes. I will post it as soon as I can.

Comment: Is it true that csv files have commas defaulted in it when using Excel spreadsheet (commas in place for the borders)? That might make sense in terms of why I'm having this trouble.

Comment: Yes hence the name "comma-separated values"

Comment: And there is no way to remove those commas in Excel? I've been trying to figure it out on how to remove those that I'm looking to remove and replace them with commas. The only way I can do that is go in Notepad and use the Replace function. And I'm not replacing all of them. Just certain ones. I guess I'll keep trying to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Those commas disappear as soon as you open the file in excel: they're only there to separate the different columns so Excel knows where to place the various values.  What you could do is concatenate the F, G and H values (with a `;` between them) into a new column I in Excel (`=F2 & ";" & G2 & ";" & H2` fill down then copy/paste values), then delete the F,G and H columns and save again as CSV.